# Make nested movieclip to fit the stage width and height

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

**Stage -> xButton -> Panel**

Panel is thrown somwere in XButton movieclip so I want to bring it into stage.
I want my panel movieclip dinamically to be at 0,0 coordinate and to exactly fit the stage...

I didn't manage to do this :|

I tried this :

```
        exitPanel.width  = main.stage.stageWidth  
        exitPanel.height = main.stage.stageHeight
         this
        exitPanel.width  = main.stage.stageWidth  - xBtn.width;
        exitPanel.height = main.stage.stageHeight - xBtn.height;
         this
        exitPanel.width  = main.stage.stageWidth  * exitPanel.scalX;
        exitPanel.height = main.stage.stageHeight * exitPanel.scaleY;

        exitPanel.x = 0;
        exitPanel.y = 0;
        exitPanel.x -= xBtn.x;
        exitPanel.y -= xBtn.y;
```

And no one works good for me.

Give me some advice please.

I check on the internet but I can't find a good solution...

Thank you !

**In FLA I have a MovieCLip named 'xButton' which has inside another movieclip named 'exitPanel' 
(exitPanel is placed somewere out od the stage view)...**

```
package com.stx.utils {

   public class XButton {

    public var main     : MovieClip;
    public var xBtn     : MovieClip;
    public var exitPanel: MovieClip;

    public function XButton(m:MovieClip) {
        main = m;
        init();
        xBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onX);
    }

    private function init() : void {
        xBtn = main.getChildByName('xButton') as MovieClip;=
        exitPanel = xBtn.getChildByName('exitPanel') as MovieClip;

         //this is ok, my stage is HD
        trace(main.stage.stageWidth);  //1280 
        trace(main.stage.stageHeight); //720

        //tried
        exitPanel.width  = main.stage.stageWidth  
        exitPanel.height = main.stage.stageHeight
         this
        exitPanel.width  = main.stage.stageWidth  - xBtn.width;
        exitPanel.height = main.stage.stageHeight - xBtn.height;
         this
        exitPanel.width  = main.stage.stageWidth  * exitPanel.scalX;
        exitPanel.height = main.stage.stageHeight * exitPanel.scaleY;
        //no one works
        exitPanel.x = 0;
        exitPanel.y = 0;
        exitPanel.x -= xBtn.x;
        exitPanel.y -= xBtn.y;
    }

    private function onX(e:MouseEvent) : void {
        ...
    }
}
```

}

Document Class

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public function Main() {
            new XButton(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally solve it!**
  this is the answer:

for x and y I should use globalToLocal function.
For width and height I should devide by exitPanel parent

**here is the code:**

```
            var lp:Point = exitPanel.parent.globalToLocal(new Point(0,0));
            exitPanel.x = lp.x;
            exitPanel.y = lp.y;
            exitPanel.width  = main.stage.stageWidth  / xBtn.scaleX;
            exitPanel.height = main.stage.stageHeight / xBtn.scaleY;
```

Answer (score 0):

'main' may not be what you want. Try:

```
exitPanel.width  = stage.stageWidth  
exitPanel.height = stage.stageHeight
exitPanel.x = 0;exitPanel.y = 0;
```

If 'main' is your document class make sure that it extends 'MovieClip' or 'Sprite.' Now when you refer to 'main.stage' you're referring to a Display Object that can actually HAVE a stage.

So this code will work:

```
 package     
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function main() 
        {
            exitPanel.width  = stage.stageWidth;  
            exitPanel.height = stage.stageHeight;
            exitPanel.x = 0; exitPanel.y = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

You can also say: `this.stage.stageWidth`  or  `exitPanel.stage.stageWidth` but you CANT say `main.stage.stageWidth` because 'main' is a class and classes don't have a 'stage' property. Only display objects or instances that inherit from display objects have a 'stage' property.

Comment: but main is my reference to document class. I call from Document class like this : MyClass(this); In my class : main  = 'this'

Comment: exitPanel.x = 0;exitPanel.y = 0; // this is relative to his parrent to xButton, and it will not work how I want. I want to be puted at 0,0 of stage not of it parent.

Comment: if I trace trace(main.stage.stageWidth);
   trace(main.stage.stageHeight);  is ok it shows 1280, 720

Comment: Don't work for me. I told you 'main' is a Movieclip which is linked to the Document class and is normal to say main.stage.stageWidth... And if I print this, it will show 1280 (my stage width). So, I think you dont understand my problem.

Comment: Well, I tested the exact code that I gave to you and it most definitely works! If it is NOT working for you please post your entire code and a link to your .fla and maybe we can figure out what's going on there.

Comment: for correct test you should have this. FLA-> an movieClip on stage named 'xButton', inside this button somehwere out of the stage put another movieclip named 'xPanel'. ok now you have on the stage xButton which contains xPanel (xButton->xPanel). Document class named 'Main'. and in another package which is near your fla let say com.classes.utils you have a clas named ButtonX which in constructor take one argument (movieClip) and it initilize xBtn whith getChildByName, the saame happens with exitPanel which is equal to xBtn.getChildByName('xButton')....Then I have that init function for resizing